# How to add A record only in DigitalOcean DNS using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, digital-ocean

How can I add an A record to an existing DigitalOcean DNS domain using Ansible?

I tried the following:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - digital_ocean_domain:
        state: present
        name: my.example.com

    - digital_ocean_domain:
        state: present
        name: test1.my.example.com
        ip: 127.0.0.1
```

But the second task adds a full domain `test1.my.example.com` (with NS records) along the A record for `test1.my.example.com`.

I wanted to add just the A record for `test1.my.example.com` to the domain created in first task.

For reasons quite obvious, I don't want a separate domain for every single host.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such ansible module (although there **was** one making its way through PR, across *three repo renames* but it was closed by the ansible team), but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35669) you can track.

In the meantime, you can accomplish that via [the Domain Record API](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#create-a-new-domain-record), which you can package up into a "playbook local" module, if having this much yaml bothers you.

```
- uri:
    url: "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains/{{ dns_domain }}/records"
    headers:
      accept: application/json
      authorization: Bearer {{ oauth2_token }}
    return_content: yes
  register: domain_records_resp

- when: domain_host not in (domain_records_resp.domain_records | map(attribute="name") | list)
  uri:
    method: POST
    url: "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/domains/{{ dns_domain }}/records"
    headers:
      authorization: Bearer {{ oauth2_token }}
    body: '{{ create_record | to_json }}'
    body_format: json
    return_content: yes
  vars:
    create_record:
        data: 127.0.0.1
        flags: null
        name: '{{ domain_host }}'
        port: null
        priority: null
        tag: null
        ttl: 1800
        type: A
        weight: null
```

Answer (score 1):

The `community.digitalocean.digital_ocean_domain_record` has been [added](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.digitalocean/blob/f93b52c7cd0ed78b7864a7f0d650143e43d59e3e/plugins/modules/digital_ocean_domain_record.py) to the collection.

You can install it with:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.digitalocean
```

Given an existing domain (with NS & SOA records), you should be able to add a specific record like so:

```
- name: Create Droplet
  community.digitalocean.droplet: {...}
  register: dx

- name: Create DNS Entry for Droplet
  community.digitalocean.digital_ocean_domain_record:
      state: present
      example: "{{ domain }}"
      type: A
      name: "www"
      data: "{{ dx.data.ip_address }}"
```

This example registers the public IP address of a new droplet as `www.{{ domain }}`, where `domain=example.com`